# Problema con slider de imagenes en jquery

Tags: jquery, slider

este código ha dejado de funcionar:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Galeria imágenes -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#peques img").click(function(){
            var imagen=$(this).attr("src");
            $("#grande").attr("src",imagen);
        });
    })
</script>
```

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea? ¿La versión de `JQuery`? En la consola del navegador me salen estos errores:

> SyntaxError: illegal character jquery-1.10.1.min.js:5:639
>
> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: ¿Has definido algún alias para `jQuery`?, suele ser un còdigo similar a este: `var jq = jQuery.noConflict();`. Si es así tendras que llamar al jQuery por este alias: en vez de `$(document)` ► `jq(document)`

Comment: No, no he definido ningún alias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado, he actualizado a jquery 1.8 y ya funciona:

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/></script>
```

. Tema cerrado. Gracias!